# Set progress bar on bottom of card

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position

I am looking set the progress bar at the bottom of this card.

I have tried **`align-self: flex-end`** and **`margin-top: auto`** to no success.

Live example: http://jsbin.com/zopaxep/edit?html,output

How can I do this?

Comment: First, the code snippet that reproduce the issue should primarily be _within_ the question, not as an external link, second, normally flowed children respect their parent's padding, so to force them beyond, use positioning (or remove the padding)

Comment: As far as I know a external link is valid...when did that change

Comment: Then you might want to read [ask] and [mcve] a second time. And the reason is simple, when your link dies, so does the question, and questions here at SO are not only for you, they are for all the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what are you looking for? If yes this will work, I guess.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="description" content="Polymer 2.0 Basic Legacy Element">
    <base href="//polygit2.appspot.com/webcomponentsjs+:v1/custom-elements+webcomponents+:master/shadydom+webcomponents+:master/shadycss+webcomponents+:master/polymer+:2.0-preview/components/">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="./polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./paper-progress/paper-progress.html">

    <dom-module id="my-app">
      <template>
        <style>

       paper-progress {
        width: 100%;
        --paper-progress-height: 5px;
        }

      .header {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
      }
      .header-bar {
        padding: 0 25px;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
      }

      .header-transition {
        padding: 24px 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
                    0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
                    0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
      }

      .menu-adjustment {
        padding:20px;
        display: block;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .progress-container {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        align-self: flex-end;
        width: 100%;
      }
          
        </style>
     <div class="header-transition" id="mat" hiden$="[[opened]]">

      <div class="header-bar">
        <span class="header">Title</span>

        <div class="card-actions menu-adjustment">
          <div class="" id="headerContainer">
            <button>Submit</button>
          </div>
         

      </div>

      <div class="progress-container">
        <paper-progress indeterminate class="blue"></paper-progress>
      </div>

    </div>

    </template>
      <script>
        Polymer({
          is: 'my-app',
          properties: {
            preventLoad: {
              type: Boolean,
              value: false,
            },
          }
        });
      </script>
    </dom-module>

  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app></my-app>
  </body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit 1**

positioned the progress bar to the bottom of the card

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="description" content="Polymer 2.0 Basic Legacy Element">
    <base href="//polygit2.appspot.com/webcomponentsjs+:v1/custom-elements+webcomponents+:master/shadydom+webcomponents+:master/shadycss+webcomponents+:master/polymer+:2.0-preview/components/">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="./polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./paper-progress/paper-progress.html">

    <dom-module id="my-app">
      <template>
        <style>

       paper-progress {
        width: 100%;
        --paper-progress-height: 5px;
        }

      .header {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
      }
      .header-bar {
        padding: 0 25px;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
      }

      .header-transition {
        padding: 24px 0;
        
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
                    0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
                    0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
      }

      .menu-adjustment {
        
        display: block;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .progress-container {
        position:relative;
        bottom:0px;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .footer{
        position:relative;
        bottom:-23px;
        width:inherit;
        left:-25px;
        background-color:transparent;
      }
          
        </style>
        <div class="header-transition" id="mat" hiden$="[[opened]]">

          <div class="header-bar">
            <span class="header">Title</span>

            <div class="card-actions menu-adjustment">
              <div class="" id="headerContainer">
                <button>Submit</button>
              </div>


            </div>

            <div class="footer">
              
               <div class="progress-container">
                      <paper-progress indeterminate class="blue"></paper-progress
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

    </template>
      <script>
        Polymer({
          is: 'my-app',
          properties: {
            preventLoad: {
              type: Boolean,
              value: false,
            },
          }
        });
      </script>
    </dom-module>

  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app></my-app>
  </body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but no. I need the progress bar to be actually on the bottom of the card....inside the card but at the edge.... at the end of the padding.